# LINQ DataTable Performance Drops with .csv Source

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on an application that can identify differentials between two files. The input files can be excel, delimitted, or fixed width, so I am building the application to convert the source files into a standard data table that can be queried through LINQ. One portion of the app needs to identify duplicate records based on a supplied ID column in order to check for changes in other fields. For some reason my LINQ statement for this doesn't like the data provided from my Delimited ToDataTable() function and takes nearly 15 minutes to complete. If I save the Delimited file as Excel and run it through the Excel ToDataTable() everything finishes in about 10 seconds.

Excel ToDataTable():

```
    public override DataTable ToDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dtSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + Sheets[0].SheetName + "]", con);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Delimited ToDataTable():

```
    public override DataTable ToDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        if (HasHeaders)
        {
            string[] headers = Parser.ReadFields();

            for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                dt.Columns.Add(headers[i]);
        }

        while (!Parser.EndOfData)
            dt.Rows.Add(Parser.ReadFields());

        return dt;
    }
```

So the process reads in two files (current & history), converts them both to a DataTable and then runs the LINQ query below:

```
    var duplicateIDs = from ht in HistoryTable.AsEnumerable()
                       join ct in CurrentTable.AsEnumerable() on ht.Field<object>(IndexName) equals ct.Field<object>(IndexName)
                       select new { MatchedID = ht[IndexName] };

    var duplicateRecords = (from dups in duplicateIDs
                            join currentFields in CurrentTable.AsEnumerable() on dups.MatchedID equals currentFields.Field<object>(IndexName)
                            select new { Fields = currentFields, SortOrder = 1 })
                            .Union
                            (from dups in duplicateIDs
                             join historyFields in HistoryTable.AsEnumerable() on dups.MatchedID equals historyFields.Field<object>(IndexName)
                             select new { Fields = historyFields, SortOrder = 2 })
                           .OrderBy(o => o.Fields.Field<object>(IndexName))
                           .ThenBy(o => o.SortOrder);
```

I can iterate over my duplicateIDs with no issues, but when I open a for each loop on the duplicateRecords everything hangs for the larger delimited files. Both types of files index their tables, so the only difference between them is the way they are initialized.

UPDATE #1
Thanks NetMage for pointing me towards some of the inefficiencies. I didn't realize I was effectively running the first statement twice within the second statement. You suggested moving away from the anonymous types but I found that I could neatly encapsulate both records within one anonymous object and get rid of the second statement completely:

```
        var duplicates = from ht in HistoryTable.AsEnumerable()
                       join ct in CurrentTable.AsEnumerable() on ht.Field<object>(IndexName) equals ct.Field<object>(IndexName)
                       select new { History = ht.ItemArray, Current = ct.ItemArray};
```

This runs within a second or two!

Comment: I should mention that I'm using the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser for the csv reads. Also, if I wasn't clear in the original description, I just need to identify the IDs that exist in both tables (current & history), union the related records, and iterate over the results.

Comment: Can you show how the indexing is done/differs for the two `DataTable`s? Is there some reason you create a single field anonymous object for `duplicateIds` instead of just selecting the value itself? I would suggest you put `.ToList()` on the end of the `duplicateIDs` creation since the `duplicateRecords` query otherwise has to run it twice. Also, `Union` makes sure the results are distinct, if you don't need that, using `Concat` is much better.